# Want to fetch records but counting on distinction of column with duplicate values using HQL

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hql

I have BusinessParty POJO Object mapped to table BP table,
Requests POJO object mapped to REQUESTS table.

One BP have multiple requests in REQUESTS table by Foreign Key.

I want to fetch requests just by giving number of count of BPs required to DAO and get all requests for that count (Say e.g. 10) BPs requests from REQUEST table.

I am tried initially in Oracle SQL

```
select * from REQUESTS where BP_ID in (select distinct BP_ID from REQUESTS where ROWNUM<=200);
```

But in this inner query searches into 200 rows and it found 95 BPs and Outer query return me 217 records of REQUESTS which of 95 BPs.

again I have to convert resulting query into HQL.

Don't know how can i fetch all requests for specific count of BPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, if I understood, what you want to do, but I think the problem is, that Oracle limits the rownum and than makes distinct. If you want to get 200 unique BP_IDs, you have to make another sub-query:

```
select * 
from REQUESTS 
where BP_ID in (select BP_ID from (Select distinct BP_ID from REQUESTS) where ROWNUM<=200);
```

Comment: I want to convert this sql Query into HQL Query. How can I do that? Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know which keyword will work in place of ROWNUM in HQL while using in Inner query.